# How do I break out of 2 loops? (Python)

Tags: python, loops, methods, break, blackjack

There has to be a better way to do this... Any ideas? This is a basic blackjack game for CS1.

2 main things bugging me:

1. How do I break out of the loop twice? Ex. The dealer wins, and and then it asks "stay or hit?", because it's still on the player's turn/loop.
2. The breaks seem really cruddy. There's so much copy-pasted code.

Thanks! Any help appreciated.

```
import random
import sys
# game, hand, deck


class Deck:
    theDeck = []
    card = 0

    def createDeck(self):
        for x in range(2, 15):
            for y in range(1, 5):
                self.theDeck.append(x)

    def extractCard(self):
        card = self.theDeck.pop(random.randrange(1, len(self.theDeck) - 1))
        return card


class Game:
    dealerTotal = [0, 0]
    playerTotal = 0
    deck = Deck()
    deck.createDeck()

    def reset(self):
        self.dealerTotal = [0, 0]
        self.playerTotal = 0

    def dealerEnd(self):
        if self.dealerTotal[0] == 21 or self.dealerTotal[1] == 21:
            print("BLACKJACK! Game over.\n\nDEALER'S TURN")
            self.reset()
            return True    
        elif self.dealerTotal[0] > 21 and self.dealerTotal[1] > 21:
            print("PLAYER WINS! Game over.\n\nDEALER'S TURN")
            self.reset()
            return True
        return False

    def playerEnd(self):
        if self.playerTotal == 21:
            print("BLACKJACK! Game over.\n\nDEALER'S TURN")
            self.reset()
            return True
        elif self.playerTotal > 21:
            print("DEALER WINS! Game over.\n\nDEALER'S TURN")
            self.reset()
            return True
        return False

    def dealerChangeTotal(self,hold):
        self.dealerTotal[0] += hold
        self.dealerTotal[1] += hold
        print("Total ::"), self.dealerTotal
        self.dealerEnd()

    def playerChangeTotal(self,hold):
        self.playerTotal += hold
        print("Total ::"), self.playerTotal
        self.playerEnd()

    def play(self):
        while len(self.deck.theDeck) > 0:

            print("DEALER'S TURN")
            if self.dealerTotal[0] >= 16 or self.dealerTotal[1] >= 16:
                print("I can't take. Your go.")
            while self.dealerTotal[0] < 16 or self.dealerTotal[1] < 16:
                hold = self.deck.extractCard()
                if hold == 14:
                    print("Card :: ace")
                    self.dealerTotal[0] += 1
                    self.dealerTotal[1] += 11
                    print("Total ::"), self.dealerTotal
                    if self.dealerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 13:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: king")
                    self.dealerChangeTotal(hold)
                    if self.dealerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 12:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: queen")
                    self.dealerChangeTotal(hold)
                    if self.dealerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 11:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: jack")
                    self.dealerChangeTotal(hold)
                    if self.dealerEnd() == True:
                        break
                else:
                    print("Card ::"), hold
                    self.dealerChangeTotal(hold)
                    if self.dealerEnd() == True:
                        break

            print("\n\nPLAYER'S TURN")
            while True:
                hold = self.deck.extractCard()
                if hold == 14:
                    print("Card :: ace")
                    self.playerTotal += input("Do you want a 1 or an 11? ")
                    print("Total ::"), self.playerTotal
                    response = raw_input("Stand or hit? ")
                    if response == "stand":
                        break
                    if self.playerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 13:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: king")
                    self.playerChangeTotal(hold)
                    response = raw_input("Stand or hit? ")
                    if response == "stand":
                        break
                    if self.playerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 12:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: queen")
                    self.playerChangeTotal(hold)
                    response = raw_input("Stand or hit? ")
                    if response == "stand":
                        break
                    if self.playerEnd() == True:
                        break
                elif hold == 11:
                    hold = 10
                    print("Card :: jack")
                    self.playerChangeTotal(hold)
                    response = raw_input("Stand or hit? ")
                    if response == "stand":
                        break
                    if self.playerEnd() == True:
                        break
                else:
                    print("Card ::"), hold
                    self.playerChangeTotal(hold)
                    response = raw_input("Stand or hit? ")
                    if response == "stand":
                        break
                    if self.playerEnd() == True:
                        break


            print("\n\n")

#... Main?
game = Game()
game.play()
```

Comment: Instead of multiple looping constructs and copy/pasted code; why don't you break this up more into reusable functions and/or objects?

Answer (score 6):

Create a flag at start of outer loop as FALSE ...
Then in inner loop, set it TRUE when needed to break 2 loops, there you go, now you will break the inner loop, and check the flag in outer loop, if it is true, the break out of this outer loop too.

```
while ...:
    flag = 0
    while ...:
        #  point where you want 2 loops to break
        flag = 1
        break
        
    # break out of this too :P
    if flag == 1:
        break
```